How to apply a formula to only certain functions
I have a list of teams that all have a number.
I have a function that determines the common values of each team.
I need to find a way for this function to automatically detect when the team number changes. Obviously, mine is longer and have tens of rows

=LET(rng;B2:B5;col;TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;rng);",";;TRUE;TRUE)); TEXTJOIN(",";;TOCOL(IF(BYROW(UNIQUE(col);LAMBDA(x;SUM(--(x=col))))=ROWS(rng);UNIQUE(col);1/0);3))
I tried to use an If formula with something like =IF ( A2<>A3; ... ) but I don't think this is the way and I don't know how to use VBA and macro

I've just replaced your LET(rng,B2:B5, with LET(rng,FILTER(Table1[Column2],Table1[Teams]=A2),, and wrapped it in an IF formula so that it only populates if the team is different from the previous row.
Just note I use , instead of ; to separate the arguments.
=IF(A2<>A1,LET(rng,FILTER(Table1[Column2],Table1[Teams]=A2), col,TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,rng),",",,TRUE,TRUE)), TEXTJOIN(",",,TOCOL(IF(BYROW(UNIQUE(col),LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(x=col))))=ROWS(rng),UNIQUE(col),1/0),3))),"")



To make this more flexible, I'd change the IF(A2<>A1 to IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2;A2)=1. That way, if for example A3 changes to 3, it won't redo the next time 1 or 3 comes along.

I would go for the following approach:

Split every cell entry into an array (for that, you can use the TextSplit() worksheet function).
Merge all of those together, as in a union of sets.
On that merged union, launch the Unique() worksheet function in order to find the unique identifiers).
For each of those unique identifiers, use the CountIf() on each of the TextSplit-ted arrays.
Take the sum of each of those CountIf() functions. If that corresponds to the number of rows all together, you have found an entry which exists in every cell.

As far as that union-ing is concerned, I am only able to "unionite" strings, so I have performed the following experiment: put "1,2,3,4,5"in cell "B1" and "2,3,4,5,6" in cell "B2", and use the following formula:
=UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;B1;B2);","))

As you can see, the idea was:

Join "B1" and "B2" into "1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,6"
split it into [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]"
and take the unique entries

This was meant to be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] but on my PC, it yields [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].
Although my results are wrong, I'm quite sure that my approach is correct.
Maybe someone with better Excel knowledge can correct this?

If you want to use UNIQUE in this way, you should TEXTSPLIT into rows, not columns. Just add an extra blank like so:=UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,B1,B2),,","))

Here's a bit more generalized version (using Microsoft 365)
Main logic (very simlar to the suggestions above)

Get unique values for each team (removing duplicates)
Find intsection between the groups by combing two groups at time and removing values occuring only once.

As you can see in the example, this does not rely on ordering by team number.
common_values_for_team
= LAMBDA(
    team_number,
    LET(
      teams_values,
      unique_values_for_team(team_number),
      IF(ROWS(teams_values) = 1,
         teams_values,
         REDUCE(,teams_values,
           LAMBDA(
             acc,
             row,
             TEXTJOIN(
               col_delim,,
               intersection_a_b(
                TEXTSPLIT(acc, col_delim), TEXTSPLIT(row, col_delim))))))))

intersection_a_b get common values in two rows (unique(combined)-once)
= LAMBDA(a,b,
    LET(
      ab,
      HSTACK(a, b),
      u,
      UNIQUE(ab, TRUE),
      once,
      UNIQUE(ab,TRUE,TRUE),
      is_common,
      ISNA(MATCH(u,once,0)),
      FILTER(u,is_common,"none")))

unique_values_for_team (get unique values for a team in a single column)
=LAMBDA(n, unique_values_as_delim_text(split_col_to_numbers(team_values(n))))

unique_values_as_delim_text (convert from rows and columns with values to single column)
=LAMBDA(area,BYROW(area,LAMBDA(row,TEXTJOIN(col_delim,,UNIQUE(row,TRUE)))))

Other functions and variables:



Name
Refers to




col_delim
=","


row_delim
="|"






split_col
=LAMBDA(single_col,TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(row_delim,,single_col), col_delim,row_delim))


split_col_to_numbers
=LAMBDA(col,IFNA(VALUE(TRIM(split_col(col))),""))






team_values
=LAMBDA(number,FILTER(Table1[Column2],  Table1[Teams]=number))



Sample data and result (teams table defines as Table1)



Team Number
Common values




=SORT(UNIQUE(Table1[Teams]))
=BYROW(E2#,LAMBDA(number,common_values_for_team(number)))






Teams
Column2


Team Number
Common values




1
4,7,9,3,1


1
7,9


1
7,5,2,9,4


2
8


1
8,5,7,9


3
3,4,2


5
4,1,8,3,8,9,7


4
1,8,2,5


2
4,8,2


5
4,1,8,3,9,7


2
1,2,7,8






2
3,1,8,6






2
6,3,4,9,3,1,8






2
0,4,8,6,9






3
8,3,4,7,2






3
2,4,6,9,3






4
1,8,2,5






1
3,7,9







